# How to make scroll bar permanently visible on Mac OS using CSS or jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, macos

I want to make scroll bars permanently visible on Mac OS, but I don't know how to do it, I tried something like :

```
var topVal = $(".content").css("top"); //alert(topVal);
var val=parseInt(topVal.replace("px",""));
val=val+20;
$(".content").css("top", val+"px");
```

also something like this :

```
var g=jQuery('.all-notifications-feed');
g.scrollTop+=1;
g.scrollTop-=1;
```

of course I used interval to repeat code every 0.2 sec.

Comment: have you tried style="overflow:scroll" ? This would always give you a horizontal and vertical scroll bar

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I agree with @DinoMyte ,

```
 overflow:scroll
```

would be a good option for this if all you want to do is show the scroll bar.

Here is the link to overflow property .

http://www.w3schools.com/cssreF/pr_pos_overflow.asp

Also another way to force the scroll in safari

http://jsfiddle.net/simurai/UsvLN/

Credit goes to http://simurai.com/blog/2011/07/26/webkit-scrollbar

Hope this helps.

Comment: I use overflow: scroll, but there is a problem that on Mac OS scroll bars hides after less than second and I need to make them visible permanently but without asking customers to change settings of his OS

Comment: hey i have updated my answer check it out,i tested it with online browser testing tools  seems to be staying on. let me know how it works